# New Google ReCaptcha not posting/receiving 'g-recaptcha-response'

Tags: php, captcha, recaptcha

I am trying to implement Googles new 'NoCaptcha' on my site. So far I have the widget appearing fine, but it does not verify on my PHP page.

My code is set up as such:

In `<head>`

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

Client Side:

```
<form id="contactform" action="bookingverify.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name" size="41">
<!--OTHER FORM INPUTS-->
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="mypublickey"></div>
</form>
```

Server Side (bookingverify.php)

```
  $captcha;
  if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
       $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
     }
  if(!$captcha){
      echo '<h2>Please check the the captcha form.</h2>';
       exit;
   }

  $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=myprivatekey&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

  if($response.success==false){
          echo '<h2>You are spammer</h2>';
  }
  else{
     //SEND MAIL
  }
```

I've tried echoing `$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']` but it appears empty. It's like that variable is not being posted to the php.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Your code ran fine on my test server with my own private / public key. It seems trivial, but the only thing I had to add - do you have a submit button in your other form inputs? This is what actually posts the data to your PHP script.

```
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Otherwise, add `var_dump($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);` to your bookingverify.php and see what it outputs.

Comment: Yes sorry I have put the submit button in - just forgot to include it above. When I do the dump I just get NULL - the PHP just is not receiving the private key data

Comment: I have the same issue of MeltingDog, and I have not clue how to solve it

Answer (score 1):

OK I have no idea why but I deleted the `exit;` in the 2nd IF statement and it worked. Weird.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as you. But you need that exit otherwise they can get through without even doing the verification lol. I'm not sure why it's happening.

Answer (score -2):

i had a similar issue. Apparently if you dont click the checkbox the $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] comes in empty. so just make sure you click it when testing