# Google ReCaptcha not posting 'g-recaptcha-response'

Tags: php, recaptcha

This question has been asked before: [New Google ReCaptcha not posting/receiving 'g-recaptcha-response'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27683888/new-google-recaptcha-not-posting-receiving-g-recaptcha-response) - but there was no proper answer.

I have the exact same set up as him, but the code fails here:

```
if(!$captcha){
   exit;
}
```

so `$captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']` seems to be empty.

[new google recaptcha with checkbox server side php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27274157/new-google-recaptcha-with-checkbox-server-side-php) = The 2nd answer here also doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone know why this could happen?

Comment: Make sure you have the api js loaded in the ```<head>``` of your document and that there are no javascript errors. Additionally you could check the dom with Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools to see if the form field is there.

Comment: Same issue here, my response is empty. Answers on both posts didn't help. Could there be a networking restriction that is blocking the response? The reCAPTCHA site doesn't show any data for mine yet, but maybe I have to wait more than a day.

Comment: don't know if it helps you. but i downloaded a bootstrap template and i encountered this. the form is not actually posting, there's a js script that first validates data entry, empty fields etc. if all ok it builds up the POST request and posts it. i had to edit the js script to include the g-recaptcha-response field... hope this helps :)

Answer (score 22):

I encountered this issue and found that my form was closing prematurely in the DOM because it was inside a table. ReCaptcha sets up a display:none g-recaptcha-response textarea and later fills in the data when you complete the captcha. It seems to look for children of the form that the div is in and thus couldn't find the g-recaptcha-response it had initially created. I put the form around the table and it worked fine after that.

Comment: That was it for me too.

Comment: yep! - implementing this on bad legacy code w/ `<table><form>[table-contents]</form></table>` and just sitched to `<form><table>[table-contents]</table></form>` this answer spared me 1 hour unnecessary debugging ! :)

Comment: In my case I did not add this in my head tag `<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>`

Comment: when you give google div id like this `#g-recaptcha-response` than it also didnt produce response. so dont give name like this.

Answer (score 8):

Check if you have the following present in the part where you **show the form to the user**:

1. Between `<form>` and `</form>`:

   `<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_public_key"></div>`
2. Before the closing `</head>` tag:

   `<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>`
3. Check that your form uses `post` as method, ...

   `<form method="post" ...>`

If these are correct, at least some `$_POST['grecaptcha-response']` should be coming your way. Check those first in the resulting client side html code (in many browsers by pressing`Strg`+`U` while looking at the user-form) - rather than your server side code - it's easier to work with that knowledge. If all of those are in place even at the client, this will however be a tough one ^^

Comment: I found the "honeypot" method for keeping out spam bots and decided to go with that as it's far easier. Is there any reason why it I should use recaptcha instead though?

Comment: @frosty: With a honeypot you are ONLY able to fool very general bots, if someone specifically targets you it is rather worthless. Also you have to be careful with people using form fillers (customers that let the browser fill their forms for them), which will be fooled as well, and the (well meaning) user might be supprised to be called a spammer by your site ^^. If you are fine with that, it is a valid option that will (only) protect you from the more general spambots. But I personally would recommend recaptcha for sure, it's not that complicated.

Comment: @frosty: If you have checked the points of this answer, you only need to check the recaptcha when validating the form. See following answer for a ready-to-use function, and you are done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27274157/new-google-recaptcha-with-checkbox-server-side-php/30749288#30749288

Answer (score 5):

Today I had this same issue (`g-recaptcha-response` had no value upon submit) on a website of a colleague. Turns out that the tag `<form` was mistakenly nested right after the opening tag `<table` (not inside a td, but directly after `<table`).
This was causing the issue.
After moving the tag `form` in way it wrapped the `table`, the value of `g-recaptcha-response` was correctly posted to server side after submit.

Comment: I had the same issue in an old code that was never mine. I changed the position of <form> and </form> tags to outside the of the tags <table> and </table> and it is working now. Thanks zed.

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same problem. It was not a `<table>` tag causing the problem but it was a `<div>` tag causing the problem.

My form was within a main `<div>` used to format the general layout of the form. The `<form>` tag doesn't HAVE to be within the main `<div>` I was using for the form layout. I moved the `<form>` tag just before my form layout `<div>` tag and it started working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Google wants your opening and closing  tags to be outside of other DOM elements such as `<table>` or `<div>`. I had the exact same issue which is now resolved. Move your...

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="abcd1234etc."></div>
```

...code to outside of any  or  tag and it will work. Seems as if Google cannot find the form and inject its form value otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on a site made with porto theme html5.
The javascript code that took care of the validation manually passed the fields, so it was necessary to add the g-captcha-response field.

In "view.contact.js"

```
// Ajax Submit
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $form.attr('action'),
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: {
        name: $form.find('#name').val(),
        email: $form.find('#email').val(),
        subject: $form.find('#subject').val(),
        messaggio: $form.find('#messaggio').val(),
        grecaptcharesponse: $form.find('#g-recaptcha-response').val()
    }

...
```

and in the php page change
`$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']  with $_POST['grecaptcharesponse']`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. After switching to Rails 7 and submitting the form via Turbo-Hotwire, the `g-recaptcha-response` was always empty. I could solve it by adding `noscript: false` to the recaptcha tag. Now it looks like this and it works well together with Turbo:

```
<%= recaptcha_tags noscript: false %>
```

Comment: I landed here from a quick google, being a Rails user. Even though this is a Ruby/Rails answer on a PHP question, I'm glad you posted it! ~~Checking to see if an issue exists on the repo now~~ Issue at https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/issues/407

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the error is the DOM

Code error

```
table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center"
form id="contacto" name="contacto" method="post" action="xxx"
```

Code OK

```
form id="contacto" name="contacto" method="post" action="xxx"
table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center"
```

Answer (score 0):

The perfect solution is do not create your own **g-recaptcha-response** input because google will fill it with the response and still yet go ahead creating another **g-recaptcha-response** textarea but then will not fill it with the response value

Answer (score 0):

If you are using reCaptcha v3, you have to explicitly define **g-recaptcha-response** in your form by attaching an ID to it.

If you are using reCaptcha v2, just make sure to put recaptchacontainer with in your form

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me. I'm using `react-google-recaptcha`. And it seems like you have to await/resolve the `recaptchaRef.current.execute()` Promise beforehand.

Without resolving the promise, it worked half the times, and that is when I call `recaptchaRef.current.getValue()`. Otherwise it would return an empty value.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, the PHP INI configuration of the server must accept "Allow opening of URLs as files", otherwise reCaptcha returns empty.

Answer (score -1):

First check if recaptcha is set

```
if(!isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) ){
    die ("Error: Not valid recaptcha on form");
}
```

Also have a look at this [simple PHP tutorial](http://blog.itslum.com/2015/11/15/google-recaptcha-step-by-step-guide/) for simple debugging.

Comment: Link no longer available.

Comment: @Jimmy Adaro Wayback Machine to the rescue! http://web.archive.org/web/20151117185717/http://blog.itslum.com/2015/11/15/google-recaptcha-step-by-step-guide/