# Can't get recaptcha to work on our site, no matter what I try, following directions

Tags: recaptcha

The user always gets rejected for some reason.

On the client side, we have exactly what's called for v2, with the

`<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>`

above the closing head tag, and the

`<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="CLIENT SIDE SECRET">`

in the proper spot on the form. (Our proper secret is in the CLIENT SIDE SECRET spot.)

On the server side, we have:

```
$response = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];
$url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
$data = array(
    'secret' => 'SERVER SIDE SECRET',
    'response' => $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"],
    // for Cloudflare
    'remoteip' => (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"]) ? $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
);
$options = array(
    'http' => array (
        'method' => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$verify = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$captcha_success = json_decode($verify);

if ($captcha_success->success==false) {
    echo "<h3>You are a bot! Go away!</h3>";
    exit;
} else if ($captcha_success->success==true) {
    //echo "<h3>You are not not a bot!</h3>";
}
```

(Again, the proper secret is in the right spot.) I've tried some different code on the server side, and nothing has worked.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, finally figured this out. It's very simple: the form was inside a table, and according to another [post I finally found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35281415/7347610), because of that,  the form was closing prematurely in the DOM, and Recaptcha couldn't find the g-recaptcha-response it had initially created. Putting the `<form>` tags outside the table solved the problem.

I'll bet this is a pretty common mistake, I'm surprised it was so hard to find the solution. I hope this helps someone else experiencing this very frustrating problem.