# Google ReCaptcha not posting 'g-recaptcha-response' on SOME pages

Tags: php, recaptcha

I have been having this issue for a while and I cant figure it out. My Google recaptcha code seems to work on some websites - but the exact same code when added to other websites (or even other pages within the same website) won't work.
When it doesn't work, if I do a var_dump($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']); (on the second page) I get NULL.

My initial/form code:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxxx"></div>
```

My verification page code:

```
$gRecaptcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=xxxxx&response=".$gRecaptcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
if($response.success==false || !$gRecaptcha){
    die('xxxx');
}
```

There are other's that posted this question as well, but it doesn't seem any of them have a solution posted (they all just switched to a different captcha).
Any suggestions what to check next?

Answer (score 0):

Your condition inside `if` clause is wrong. The API response is a json object, like this:

```
{
  "success": true|false,
  "challenge_ts": timestamp,  // timestamp of the challenge load (ISO format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ)
  "hostname": string,         // the hostname of the site where the reCAPTCHA was solved
  "error-codes": [...]        // optional
}
```

Here's the reference:

- [Verifying the user's response](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify#api-response)

So first you have to decode it using `json_decode()` function and then check the status of user's response.

Hence your code should be like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
    //get verified response data

    //your site secret key
    $secret = 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY';

    $gRecaptcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $gRecaptcha = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secret."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

    $response = file_get_contents($gRecaptcha);
    $responseData = json_decode($response);

    if($responseData->success){
        // success
    }else{
        // failure
    }
}
```

Comment: I will switch it, but that is not the issue. I am getting NULL as the post from g-recaptcha-response

Comment: Your code will let it go through even if there is an issue that I am having but that's because you are wrapping everything in `if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){` which just ignores it completely when its null and lets it go through even if the recaptcha wasn't checked off at all

Comment: @Devpaq The `if` condition will be true *only* if there's a response from user's side, otherwise not. Do `var_dump($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);`, is it showing `NULL`?

Comment: @Devpaq May be [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27683888/new-google-recaptcha-not-posting-receiving-g-recaptcha-response) will help you debug the issue further. And please show how you're displaying the reCaptcha widget, I mean the HTML form.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);` is showing `NULL` which is why I had my original question.
The recapthca widget is basically what I showed in my question
`<form name='orderInfo' id='orderInfo' method='post'  action='<?=htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])?>'> 
<!-- other form inputs -->
<div class="dn-onefull" align="center">
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXXXX"></div>
</div>`
As I mentioned, the same code works on some pages/sites and not on others. I cant think of anything conflicting

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:
Step 1 :
put this code for validate :

```
<?php
$secret = "Your own code";
$sitekey = "Your own code";
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
            if(!$captcha){
                header("Location: index.php?info=cap");
                exit;
            }
            $response=json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secret."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), true);
            if($response['success'] == false)
            {
                  header("Location: index.php?info=cap");
                    exit;
            }
}
    ?>
```

Step 2 : use this tag in your form :

```
<label>I'm not robot: </label>
<div class="g-recaptcha"></div>
```

Step 3 : Google API

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=CaptchaCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var CaptchaCallback = function(){
    $('.g-recaptcha').each(function(index, el) {
        grecaptcha.render(el, {'sitekey' : '<?php echo $sitekey;?>'});
        });
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Verify you have added both of these in google recaptcha:

`www.yourdomain.com` and `yourdomain.com`

Comment: This isn't correct, it would simply be "yourdomain", in fact you're no even allowed to put the www, protocol, or the .com portion in the domain list.